# Shunt regulator - smaller output voltage than the reference voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a Zener's diode with \$V_Z\$ of \$5.6V\$, an op-amp, NPN transistor and an input voltage pulsating from 14V to 17V. My task is to design a circuit with a stable \$2.8V\$ output voltage - and I kinda can't figure out, is it possible to have a regulator with an operational amplifier that will produce a smaller output voltage than Zener's (i.e. reference) voltage? If yes, then how would this circuit look like?

Assume that \$I_{Zmin}=5\text{mA}, \ I_{L} = 50 \text{mA}, \ I_{Cmax}=100\text{mA}, \ \beta=400 \frac{A}{A}\$

Comment: The arbitrary requirements sound like a homework problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson because it is a homework problem. I know that the output voltage of a simple regulator with just a resistor and a diode is \$V_Z\$, of a circuit with resistor + diode + transistor is \$V_Z-V_{BE}\$ and after adding op-amp - within \$<V_Z;V_{IN}>\$. And I just don't know/don't see a way to change the minimum output voltage

Comment: What stability level do you require? Do you have resistors and capacitors? What op-amp is the device you have?

Comment: @Andyaka It is just a homework problem without any specific op-amp model. I can use any resistors, not only from E-series. As for stability - "something around", so +-0.01V is good enough

Comment: So how would you make 2.8 volts from 5.6 volts and how would you use an op-amp to buffer it? And how would you use an NPN to buffer the op-amp output?

Comment: @Andyaka "So how would you make 2.8 volts from 5.6 volts" some voltage divider made of 2 equal resistors will do the job; "how would you use an op-amp to buffer it?" hmm, maybe connect the non-inverting input with some point between those resistors, and inverting input to the op-amp's output?

Comment: And finally.... involve the non transistor but use negative feedback from the emitter to the inverting input of the opamp.